# Best practice for associating community created contacts with Account

Tags: customer-community, lightning-community

We are implementing the Customer community, and have a requirement to implement the self-registration module. I have gone through the trailhead on setting up self-registration for community and Salesforce guides showing how we can customize the self-registration component.

One thing which I am not clear on is which business account does the customer portal contacts need to be associated with. The guide mentions having a single customer portal account that gets assigned with contacts created through the community.

My understanding was these users who are signing up for community will be our existing customer and we already have account records in our org representing their company. In that case, these contacts which are signing up needs to be assigned to already existing accounts instead of the community portal account we create. I customized the contact creation process using apex triggers, to get associated with the appropriate account but still needed to route it through the placeholder account.

Note: We don't want to create a person account

I wanted to understand what is the best practice here and how should this be approached i.e. should all the contacts assigned to the one single customer community account, or should be routed to their appropriate business accounts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Best practice depends on couple of factors

- Volume of users that you are expecting to register
- Your organization plan to handle accounts , in short your Account planning.

If volume of users registering is greater say in magnitude of 10K and above, relating all contacts to one account is definitely not recommended as it will create [Data Skews](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.draes.meta/draes/draes_object_relationships_parent_child_data_skew.htm) and [Ownership](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.draes.meta/draes/draes_group_membership_data_skew.htm) Skews.

Now if you are creating an account for each user that registers you need to think about who will own those accounts and action on them.

Comment: Thanks Mohith for the quick response.